# How can I find out which Language was used by Translator in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-translate

In my ZF2 application I want to retrieve the language that was used to translate the page. I use the [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) as basis. In the *Module.php* I set the *Locale* like this:

```
public function onBootstrap($e){
  $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
  $translator->setLocale(
      Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])
    )
    ->setFallbackLocale('en_US');
}
```

I can retrieve the *locale* and the *fallbackLocale* from the *Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator*, but then I still don't know which one was used for the translation. Since there is also no way (as far as I didn't found one) to find out which languages where actually loaded into the translator. I can't even test myself if a translation exists for the *locale*.

Maybe I'm missing something here. I hope someone can point that out.

Comment: You could extend the `Translator` class, overwrite the `translate()` method and save the used language key in a property.

Comment: @DanielM this is an option, but I wanted to check the language in the onBootstrap Event and there the view is propably not rendered. Anyway thank you for you comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take the most simple approach. I translate the text of the language too.

Answer (score 2):

One option may be retrieving cache object and checking for the existence of the primary locale by recreating the cache key. Looking at the `loadMessages()` method it seems the cache result would contain the list of available messages.

Otherwise it seems the translate functions simply try the first locale then the fallback.

Comment: Yes translate simply tries locale and then fallback, but I would have to do the same. I use Regex for choosing the proper language file and this means I would have to replicate everything what the translator does itself (get the locale from php Locale, go to the language directory, check if the desired language is available, otherwise take fallback.) Its a lot of effort. But anyway I give you +1 for your answer.

Comment: Would something like setting up a dummy translation key in the non-default translation files and checking if that translatable – given that you know the primary locale and fall-back locale, you could tell what file is being used.

Comment: If I understand you correctly this is what I have done. See my answer.