# Get local value in layout or view in Zend Framework 2

Tags: localization, zend-framework2

How can we **get local value** (i.e: 'en' or 'en_US', 'de' etc) in layout.phtml or views in Zend Framework 2?

My local setting are exactly same as [explained here](http://samminds.com/2012/09/zend-framework-2-translate-i18n-locale/)

```
<?php
namespace FileManager;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
        $translator
          ->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
          ->setFallbackLocale('en_US');
    }

    //...
}
```

I want to get local value something like this:

```
$locale = $this->translate()->getLocale(); // <-- It's not working anyway
```

I need to use '**$locale**' it while calling google map api url to get matched locale/language. I'm calling it throughtout the application in layout.phtml

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=' . $locale);
```

So I want to make language option dynamic while calling api.

PS: I don't have any query string parameter such as 'language', It's a google api thing which I need to set in script url (if you don't know) Please don't get confused.
Not answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075506/zend-framework-2-get-locale-from-view-phprenderer)

Comment: An easy option [available here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12578706/1960969)

Comment: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20088163/1960969): `$this->plugin('translate')->getTranslator()->getLocale();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on where you want to get the Locale value from. In any case, you can do it in your controller, e.g.:

```
$locale = $this->request->getQuery('language');
$this->layout()->locale = $locale;
```

or

```
return new ViewModel(array('locale' => $locale));
```

**Edit** if you just want to get the locale from the translator, you can try this in view script:

```
$this->plugin('translate')->getTranslator()->getLocale();
```

Comment: Misunderstood! I've updated question details. We never have access to google server to get it's 'language' query variable. and google is in zf2?

Comment: @Sanju I see what you mean and added it to my answer.

Comment: sorry im new in zf2 but i'll try $request = new Request();
        
    $locale = $request->getQuery('locale');
    var_dump($locale);
but I get "null"

Comment: @icy2k you can't get it from "new Request", that object is basically empty. You should have this->request available when you're in controller.

Answer (score 1):

My version is like that

```
<?php
namespace FileManager;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Session\Container;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $application     = $e->getTarget();
        $serviceManager  = $application->getServiceManager();
        $eventManager    = $application->getEventManager();
        $events = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

        // session container
        $sessionContainer = new Container('locale');

        // test if the language in session exists
        if(!$sessionContainer->offsetExists('mylocale')){
            // doesn't so the browser lan
            if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
                $sessionContainer->offsetSet('mylocale', Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']));
            }else{
                $sessionContainer->offsetSet('mylocale', 'en_US');
            }

        }

        // translation
        $translator = $serviceManager->get('translator');
        $translator ->setLocale($sessionContainer->mylocale)
                    ->setFallbackLocale('en_US');

        $mylocale = $sessionContainer->mylocale;

        $events->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) use ($mylocale) {
            $controller      = $e->getTarget();
            $controller->layout()->mylocale = $mylocale;
        }, 100);
    }

    //...
}
```

in your layout

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=' . $this->mylocale);
```